# Куда компилируются tsx и ts файлы в react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Вопрос такой, как я знаю чтобы запустить скрипт на ts нужно сначала его скомпилировать в js. В react пишу npm start, но нигде не появляются js файлы, вопрос тогда как react понимает это.

Comment: ts компилируются tsc - react к этому отношения не имеет

Comment: Насколько мне известно, реакт под капотом использует вебпак.

Comment: используйте документацию по реакту [Добавление TypeScript в проект](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/static-type-checking.html#adding-typescript-to-a-project) чтобы изучить данную тему